# How can i display an image within a searchbox when we click on a link?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2.The code which i am using in my page is here

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".hr").click(function(){
 $("#imgs").show();
 });
  });
 </script>
<div class="hr">click</div>
<div>
 <img src="http://www.inmomundo.com/oinmonm/plugins/searchbox/images/load_blu.gif" class="imgst" style="display:none;">
  <select name="im_c" id="im_c" data-mini="true">
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">second</option>
  </select>
```

I want the above image to be display inside a select option i.e next to first.The link to jsfiddle is
http://jsfiddle.net/Y8LtK/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you want to show a spinner on the selector to give the user some feedback after pressing the test(click) button. The way I who'd approach it is to add a class to the selector and in CSS position the spinner appropriately. Use further javascript events to hide and show the spinner and get the behavior you are looking for.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".hr").click(function () {
    $("#im_c").addClass("showSpinner");
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.showSpinner {
background: url("http://www.inmomundo.com/oinmonm/plugins/searchbox/images/load_blu.gif");
background-size: 1em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 2em;
}
```

HTML

```
<button class="hr">Test</button>
<div>
<img src="http://www.inmomundo.com/oinmonm/plugins/searchbox/images/load_blu.gif" style="display:none;" width="16" height="16" name="imgstate" id="imgstate" class="imgstate" alt="cargando" />
<select data-mini="true" id="im_c">
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option vakue="2">second</option>
</select>
</div>
```

UPDATE: You did not include any of the jQuery Mobile libraries

If your selector id is `im_c` you need to target the parent div so the selector becomes `im_c-button`

```
$("#im_c-button").addClass("showSpinner");
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beRoberto/dgvWC/